# Image diff viewer SVN

Tags: windows, svn, image, tortoisesvn, diff

We use Tortoise SVN for accessing our SVN server.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a image diff viewer that would show two revisions of the image side by side to see any any changes.  Similar to the TortoiseMerge that's included with it by default, only for image files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[TortoiseIDiff](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseIDiff.html) ?

Comment: Many thanks, guess I should have explored the Tortoise bin directory a little before shooting off the question..

Comment: Know of a tool that can put boxes around changed content in the images?

Answer (score 1):

[TortoiseIDiff](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseIDiff.html) does this.